# Does ARM GCC have a builtin function for the assembly 'REV' instruction?

Tags: gcc, arm

It's pretty common for compilers to have builtin intrinsic functions for processor features, but I'm having trouble finding them. Is there one to get at the 'REV' (reverse byte order of a word) instruction in ARM?

Where can I find the list of builtin functions?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

> Is there one to get at the 'REV' (reverse byte order of a word) instruction in ARM?

There is a more 'portable' form that is available on all architectures.  It is `__builtin_bswap32`.  For example the [compiler explorer](https://goo.gl/ZjWBM3) has,

```
unsigned int foo(unsigned int a)
{
  return __builtin_bswap32(a);
}
```

Giving,

```
foo(unsigned int):
        rev     r0, r0
        bx      lr
```

This is better than `__builtin_rev` would be as it will only be available on certain ARM targets (and certainly only ARM CPUs).  You can use `__builtin_bswap32` even on PowerPC, x86, etc.

Comment: There's also `__builtin_bswap16` to swap around a 16 bit integer (compiles to rev16 arm instruction)

Comment: For completeness, there's also [the matter of the peephole optimiser on -O2 and higher](https://goo.gl/MNbb1K), too ;)

Comment: Where is the list of __builtin_*?

Comment: @joe https://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gcc-5.3.0/gcc/Other-Builtins.html#Other-Builtins

Comment: You need to add a '-mcpu=' line to get the rev instruction.  Without it gcc will use the lowest generic CPU instructions, where rev doesn't exist.   You can try 'cortex-a5' Also if you add -march=armv7 -mthumb then you can get GCC ARM to produce the rev r0,r0.  Without it you get 4 instructions.  ARM64 works just fine since all supported CPUs have rev built in